# Pushing frames into FFmpeg buffer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, buffer, frames, fifo

I am trying to push the extracted frames from a video (which I did using ffmpeg) into the FFMPEG buffer. I have looked into the buffer source files of ffmpeg such as buffersrc.c and fifo.c to figure out if I can do that, but I couldn't figure out. Can anyone please tell me a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is `av_write_frame()` and `av_interleaved_write_frame()` functions. Look for small projects on github those uses these functions, so you can see how to set up RAW stream and begin to send frames.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes Sir. I understand using these functions, ffmpeg buffers the frames and sends it to the output file for ordering them according to dts. What I am trying to work on is to create a buffer manually on the sending side and store the outgoing frames. Can you please suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you need an algorithm to reorder buffers according to dts values ?

Comment: Not an algorithm exactly. I am not looking for reordering the buffers. All I am trying to do is to stream live feed from the webcam using ffmpeg to the receiver, and before sending them out, I need to push all the outgoing frames into the buffer so as to use them if any frames gets lost. For this, I was wondering if there are any ffmpeg functions I can use to create a buffer and implement it to store the outgoing frames.

Comment: What you need is already done: https://www.haivision.com/products/srt-secure-reliable-transport/ .This makes the buffering and re-sending and more (and free+open source).

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you so much.

Comment: It will work like this: let's say you currently send data A to B and A is your PC have webcam and B is remote PC (ffmpeg receiver). With SRT it will be: A->SRT(sender mode) to SRT(receiver mode)->B. SRT in between. A and B will think there is a direct connection as before.

Comment: Sir, do you by any chance know how ffmpeg uses a buffer? As in does it already have an internal buffer or do i have to add a new buffer and implement it.

Comment: As far as I know, FFmpeg uses dynamic circular buffer. Buffers frames according to reordering needs (b-frames) and pts/dts (waiting right time to output). If for some reason output delayed unexpectedly, you'll see circular buffer overrun message(s). SRT is very easy to use, check the forums you'll see examples, I'm writing this because I guess you don't use it.

Comment: Yes I haven't used SRT before. I will do check the examples. Thank you.

Comment: I am working to implement it in a few days and trying to use something new would take time. So I was wondering if ffmpeg already uses a buffer which I can modify and implement it according to my use.